# The /related and /linked results can't be correlated to their parent question. The `original_question` property is missing

Tags: bug, api

Suppose I have a list of questions (IDs) like 286254, 23157 and I want to get the linked or related questions for each.

I should be able to call `/questions/{ids}/linked` or `/questions/{ids}/related` like so:

[/2.2/questions/286254;23157/linked?site=meta](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/linked-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=286254%3B23157&filter=!-MOiNm42uNFf-OypqOO5VY4Zo9ZG*9jIn&site=meta&run=true)

But that returns results like:

```
{
  "items": [ {
      "tags": ["bug", "api"],
      "is_answered": false,
      ...
      "title": "Filter doesn&#39;t consistently return comment bodies"
    },
    {
      "tags": ["bug", "status-completed", "15-characters"],
      "is_answered": true,
      ...
      "title": "How did this question manage to get added without a title?"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  ...
}
```

Notice that there is **no way to tell *which* of the original questions (286254, 23157) that each result linked to.**

The filters for `/related` and `/linked` have `original_question` properties, and those are selected in my sample queries.  But they are not returned in the results!

Currently, the only way to know what the result links/relates to, is to limit the `ids` parameter to one question at a time.  But this contradicts [the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/linked-questions) and really chews up quota usage.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand this. Let's say I already have a list of QIDs and the info associated with that question. Now I want some additional info in terms of linked/related questions for each of the QID. The API will return a list of related/linked questions. Now how do I map the related/linked question to the original QID, ie, for each question returned I want to know the QID of the question it is related/linked to.

Comment: Ah. Your question was not clear, but good point. That makes the bug even worse...